# Error while running Plone 4.2 instance fg on Window

Tags: python, plone

While running buildout on window with Python 2.6 for Plone 4.2, All went fine. but while running instance on foreground it give me this window specific (presume) error about some file missing.

I remember on older version of Plone for installing PyWin type libary, I had to copy some dll file to window system file and I also done same for this. still I am having this error.

Any suggestion/advise would great help.

Thank for taking your time.

```
D:\rcseng\buildout>bin\instance fg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rcseng\buildout\bin\instance-script.py", line 258, in <module>
    + sys.argv[1:])
  File "d:\rcseng\buildout\eggs\plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2.8-py2.6.egg\plone
\recipe\zope2instance\ctl.py", line 614, in main
    c.onecmd(' '.join(options.args))
  File "D:\Python26\lib\cmd.py", line 219, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "d:\rcseng\buildout\eggs\zdaemon-2.0.7-py2.6.egg\zdaemon\zdctl.py", line
588, in do_fg
    self.do_foreground(arg)
  File "d:\rcseng\buildout\eggs\plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2.8-py2.6.egg\plone
\recipe\zope2instance\ctl.py", line 550, in do_foreground
    self._exitstatus = subprocess.call(command, env=env)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 470, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "D:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 833, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Does bin\instance.exe start work as expected? Or does that fail too…

Comment: FWIW, you can install the latest Plone 4.3 with vagrant. It's a much easier way to get started on windows. https://github.com/smcmahon/plonedev_vagrant

Comment: @aclark No, it doesn't work at all.